# My son/heir wants to join the Varangian Guard, should I let him?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm currently fighting to try to subjugate Ostlandet, and my son/heir prompted this message:

[image]

My current king (Jarl Tolir) is 56 years old, and I expect him to die at any moment. I just had a successful revolt for independence against the Queen of Sweeden, so I had to push his Ambition to become the King of Norway as soon as possible. I have another son, but he's a chaste-craven-homosexual (which is not heir material). If Hrane goes off to join the Varangian Guard will I lose him forever, or will he return when my current king dies?

**Should I allow my only good heir to join the Varangian Guard?**

Comment: `Chaste-craven-homosexual` Sounds like an excellent candidate for the clergy!

Comment: **Off-topic. This should be on [Parenting.StackExchange](http://parenting.stackexchange.com)**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Upon playing further, Tolir took until the ripe old age of 77 to pass. Hrane (now 48) has returned to claim the throne of Norway, along with a pleasant surprise:

[image]

Hrane now has a nice starting prestige of 279 (+200) and a bump of the royal coffers by 200 as well. Be aware, I was prompted that being a member of the Varangian Guard is dangerous, so I'm assuming that members are more likely to die than if they were sitting in a court. However, if you have more than one valid heir (even a chaste-craven-homosexual backup), I would recommend sending your sons to the Guard if they ask.

**Yes, you should let your sons join the Varangian Guard. If they return safely, they bring +200 gold/ prestige when they return for their claims and the "Varangian" trait (+2 Martial, +1 Diplomacy).**

Comment: This is nice, but anedoctical: it would be better to have a more detailed post with many possible outcomes, and some %.

Answer (score 2):

No. Your heir could come back blind and castrated, amongst other outcomes.